# Hibernate: How to Delete table data where exists in a list

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Current legacy system is using bellow single query to delete table1 records.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM TABLE 2 B WHERE
A.ID=B.ID AND A.NAME=B.NAME AND B.STATUS='Y')
```

Now the TABLE2 is moved to different database and owns by different application, but the data is exposed as webservice and we are allowed to filter by status or filter by id or filter by name, hence the resultant data is going to be a list.

I am planning to do following steps:

1. Query webservice to get all Table2 data filter by status "Y" [Filter Status]
2. Select Table1 by passing all ID's that are collected in Step 1. [Filter IDs]
3. Finally filter by name by looping through both Step2 results and Step1 results.

Is this correct way? are there any alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have Table1Entity. You can add a [@Formula](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation) with expression CONCAT(id, '_', name).

The 1. step could return list of TABLE2 values as id+"_"+name. Something like:

```
1_name1
2_name2
3_name3
```

The all you need is to remove all from TABLE1 where the formulaField IN (the list of values from step 1)